# spring-integration flow 6.1.4 throws "failed to handle" exception

Tags: spring-integration

I have upgraded my project to spring-integration 6.1.4 from 5.5.10

This method sends an xml SOAP request and gets back an xml response:

```
    public IntegrationFlow soap(HttpComponents5MessageSender httpComponents5MessageSender) {

    return f -> f

        .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "log.category.adapter",
            m -> String.join("", "Method=soap.start(#1); Header= ", m.getHeaders().toString(),
                "; Payload= ", m.getPayload().toString()))

        .transform(p -> messageCreator.createMessageWithAppHeaders(p))

        .handle(commitMarkerConfig.commitMarkerRetrievingGateway(), e -> e.id("soapJPAEndpoint").advice(exceptionConfig.retryAdvice()))

        .handle(requestPayloadService, "handleRequestPayload")

        .enrichHeaders(
            s -> s.headerExpression("requestString", "payload.requestString")
                .headerExpression("correlation-id", "payload.correlationId"))

        .handle((p, h) -> {
            try {

                return new MarshallingTransformer(soapConfig.jaxb2Marshaller(), soapConfig.resultToStringTransformer())
                    .transform(new GenericMessage<RequestPayloadInterface>((RequestPayloadInterface) p));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("SOAPReader had Exception e=" + e + " message=" + e.getMessage() + " stackTrace=" + Arrays.asList(e.getStackTrace())
                    .stream()
                    .map(x -> x.toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "[", "]")));
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })

        .handle(soapConfig.soapCallEndpoint(httpComponents5MessageSender))

        .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "log.category.adapter",
            m -> String.join("", "Method=soap.response(#2); Header= ",
                m.getHeaders().toString(), "; Payload= ", m.getPayload().toString()))

        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("message-correlation-id", m -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()))

        .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c

            .subscribe(s -> s

                .routeToRecipients(r -> r

                    .recipient("fileBackupChannel", m -> brokerConfig.getOperation().getFileBackup())

                    .recipient("amqpBackupChannel", m -> brokerConfig.getOperation().getBackupQueuing())

                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())

                .channel("nullChannel"))

            .subscribe(s -> s

                .handle(messagePayloadService, "mapMessagePayload")

                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "log.category.adapter",
                    m -> String.join("", "Method=soap.map(#3); Header= ",
                        m.getHeaders().toString(), "; Payload= ", m.getPayload().toString()))

                .enrich(e -> e.requestChannel("claimCheck.input").headerExpression("claimCheck", "payload"))

                .handle("integrationGateway", "process")));
}
```

has started throwing this exception:

> Cause= class org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException Message= Failed to handle. Stacktrace= [org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$CallbackImpl.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:175)
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.lambda$doInvoke$1(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86)
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
> org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86)
> org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:67)
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ...

Additionally, this

```
soapConfig.soapCallEndpoint(httpComponents5MessageSender)
```

has just been changed to use HttpComponents5MessageSender.

I don't believe the SOAP request is being sent because I've added Interceptors to log the outgoing request/incoming response and they are not being displayed.

How do I go about determining which method in my IntegrationFlow is causing this error?

How do I go about tracking down the cause of this error?

What logging/debugging options are available to me?

What is going wrong at AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:175 ?

What are the likely points of failure?

How would you go about tracking this down?

Mark

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about determining which method in my IntegrationFlow is causing this error?

You just don't show the whole stack trace of the error, but according to the current info it fails on the:

```
.handle(commitMarkerConfig.commitMarkerRetrievingGateway(), e -> e.id("soapJPAEndpoint").advice(exceptionConfig.retryAdvice()))
```

So, something is wrong with your `commitMarkerConfig.commitMarkerRetrievingGateway()` since the retry advice fails eventually anyway.

> How do I go about tracking down the cause of this error?

It supposed to be somewhere in the stack trace of that error. That's essentially what that line in the `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` does:

```
        catch (Exception e) { Errors
            throw new MessagingException((Message<?>) this.invocation.getArguments()[0], "Failed to handle", e);
        }
```

> What logging/debugging options are available to me?

You can enable DEBUG logging level for `org.springframework.integration` category. You also can use a Wire-Tap pattern and Message History to dump the message journey to logging channel adapter. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/configuration.html#channel-wiretap

> What is going wrong at AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:175 ?

Nothing is wrong: just your `commitMarkerConfig.commitMarkerRetrievingGateway()` fails for some reason you don't share with us yet.

> What are the likely points of failure?

The stack trace must contain all the info to determine that target endpoint for error.

> How would you go about tracking this down?

See all the previous explanations.